# How can I randomly partition, by rows ,in two text file in Bash? Example 70% and 30%

Tags: linux, bash, random, terminal, row

**input:**

5 a

5 b

5 c

4 d

6 t

1 f

7 h

5 i

6 j

5 k

output 1:

5 b

6 t

5 k

Output 2 contains the remaining values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `shuf` to generate random permutations of the file and then use `split` to generate the two files:

```
shuf input | split -l $(( $(wc -l <input) * 70 / 100 ))
```

The default prefix for `split` is `x`, so after running the command you should have two files: `xaa` (70%), and `xab` (remaining 30%).

You can control the output files for the `split` command:

```
-a, --suffix-length=N   generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
  --additional-suffix=SUFFIX  append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
-d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
                               FROM changes the start value (default 0).
```

So you can use this:

```
shuf input | split -a1 -d -l $(( $(wc -l <input) * 70 / 100 )) - output
```

Which will generate `output0` (70%), and `output1` (remaining 30%).